# SQLite android doesnt create all tables

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm building an app in Android based on a SQLite database.

Unfortunately it seems not working well, because it is capable of import just one file with sql statements out of about 50 files.

The structure is:

- I've got a ListView with multiple elements
- Once an item from the ListView is selected, starts a new Activity (ShowPoints.java) with an extra element passed between Activities with a Bundle Object, that's an int value.
- The new activity (ShowPoints) consists of a form in which the user write something and could search a table of the database.
- In ShowPoints I've written a switch that, based on the int value, set the value of another int element to one of the Raw resources in my raw folder, that's filled with some files without extension that contain SQL statements. In every file there's a "CREATE TABLE ....;" and a thousand lines like "INSERT INTO.... VALUES....;"
- In ShowPoints I create a new object MyDatabase passing the resource int (R.raw.blahblah) that creates a new DbHelper object, in which I create the database and I read from the file and then I excecute the SQL read line by line.

That it works just with one file, u_4x100, and with the the app crashes saying that there is no database.

Here's the code:

**ShowPoints.java**

```
package it.gorlux.onyourmark;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ShowPoints extends Activity {

    EditText searchText;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    MyDatabase db;
    ListView peopleLv;

    DbHelper mDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase _db;     

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_points);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int item_int = b.getInt("item");

    peopleLv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.peopleLv);
    searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchText);

    Context ctx = this;
    db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext(),item_int,this);

}

public void search(View view) {
    db.open();  //apriamo il db

    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.person, 
            db.searchLabel(searchText.getText().toString()), 
            new String[]{MyDatabase.PersonMetaData.PERSON_NAME_KEY,MyDatabase.PersonMetaData.PERSON_AGE_KEY},//queste colonne
            new int[]{R.id.nameTv,R.id.ageTv});
    peopleLv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

**MyDatabase.java**

```
package it.gorlux.onyourmark;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDatabase {

    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    Context mContext;

    DbHelper mDbHelper;

    public int res;
    public String tabella = null;

    private static final String DB_NAME="punteggi";//nome del database<!--more-->
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1; //numero di versione del nostro database

    Context ctx2;

    public MyDatabase(Context ctx, int item, Context ctx2) {

        mContext=ctx;
        this.ctx2 = ctx2;


        int item2 = item;

        switch(item) {
            case 0: {res=R.raw.d_4x100;break;}case 1: {res=R.raw.d_4x200;break;}case 2: {res=R.raw.d_4x400;break;}case 3: {res=R.raw.d_4x800;break;}case 4: {res=R.raw.d_4x1500;break;}case 5: {res=R.raw.d_100h;break;}case 6: {res=R.raw.d_100m;break;}case 7: {res=R.raw.d_200h;break;}case 8: {res=R.raw.d_200m;break;}case 9: {res=R.raw.d_400h;break;}case 10: {res=R.raw.d_400m;break;}case 11: {res=R.raw.d_800m;break;}case 12: {res=R.raw.d_1500m;break;}case 13: {res=R.raw.d_3000m;break;}case 14: {res=R.raw.d_3000siepi;break;}case 15: {res=R.raw.d_5000m;break;}case 16: {res=R.raw.d_10000m;break;}case 17: {res=R.raw.d_alto;break;}case 18: {res=R.raw.d_asta;break;}case 19: {res=R.raw.d_disco;break;}case 20: {res=R.raw.d_giavellotto;break;}case 21: {res=R.raw.d_lungo;break;}case 22: {res=R.raw.d_marcia5km;break;}case 23: {res=R.raw.d_martello;break;}case 24: {res=R.raw.d_peso;break;}case 25: {res=R.raw.d_svedese;break;}case 26: {res=R.raw.d_triplo;break;}case 27: {res=R.raw.u_4x100;break;}case 28: {res=R.raw.u_4x200;break;}case 29: {res=R.raw.u_4x400;break;}case 30: {res=R.raw.u_4x800;break;}case 31: {res=R.raw.u_4x1500;break;}case 32: {res=R.raw.u_100m;break;}case 33: {res=R.raw.u_110h;break;}case 34: {res=R.raw.u_200h;break;}case 35: {res=R.raw.u_200m;break;}case 36: {res=R.raw.u_400h;break;}case 37: {res=R.raw.u_400m;break;}case 38: {res=R.raw.u_800m;break;}case 39: {res=R.raw.u_1500m;break;}case 40: {res=R.raw.u_3000m;break;}case 41: {res=R.raw.u_3000siepi;break;}case 42: {res=R.raw.u_5000m;break;}case 43: {res=R.raw.u_10000m;break;}case 44: {res=R.raw.u_alto;break;}case 45: {res=R.raw.u_asta;break;}case 46: {res=R.raw.u_disco;break;}case 47: {res=R.raw.u_giavellotto;break;}case 48: {res=R.raw.u_lungo;break;}case 49: {res=R.raw.u_marcia10km;break;}case 50: {res=R.raw.u_martello;break;}case 51: {res=R.raw.u_peso;break;}case 52: {res=R.raw.u_svedese;break;}case 53: {res=R.raw.u_triplo;break;}       
            default : {break;}
        }   

        switch(item2) {
            case 0:{tabella="d_4x100";break;}case 1:{tabella="d_4x200";break;}case 2:{tabella="d_4x400";break;}case 3:{tabella="d_4x800";break;}case 4:{tabella="d_4x1500";break;}case 5:{tabella="d_100h";break;}case 6:{tabella="d_100m";break;}case 7:{tabella="d_200h";break;}case 8:{tabella="d_200m";break;}case 9:{tabella="d_400h";break;}case 10:{tabella="d_400m";break;}case 11:{tabella="d_800m";break;}case 12:{tabella="d_1500m";break;}case 13:{tabella="d_3000m";break;}case 14:{tabella="d_3000siepi";break;}case 15:{tabella="d_5000m";break;}case 16:{tabella="d_10000m";break;}case 17:{tabella="d_alto";break;}case 18:{tabella="d_asta";break;}case 19:{tabella="d_disco";break;}case 20:{tabella="d_giavellotto";break;}case 21:{tabella="d_lungo";break;}case 22:{tabella="d_marcia5km";break;}case 23:{tabella="d_martello";break;}case 24:{tabella="d_peso";break;}case 25:{tabella="d_svedese";break;}case 26:{tabella="d_triplo";break;}case 27:{tabella="u_4x100";break;}case 28:{tabella="u_4x200";break;}case 29:{tabella="u_4x400";break;}case 30:{tabella="u_4x800";break;}case 31:{tabella="u_4x1500";break;}case 32:{tabella="u_100m";break;}case 33:{tabella="u_110h";break;}case 34:{tabella="u_200h";break;}case 35:{tabella="u_200m";break;}case 36:{tabella="u_400h";break;}case 37:{tabella="u_400m";break;}case 38:{tabella="u_800m";break;}case 39:{tabella="u_1500m";break;}case 40:{tabella="u_3000m";break;}case 41:{tabella="u_3000siepi";break;}case 42:{tabella="u_5000m";break;}case 43:{tabella="u_10000m";break;}case 44:{tabella="u_alto";break;}case 45:{tabella="u_asta";break;}case 46:{tabella="u_disco";break;}case 47:{tabella="u_giavellotto";break;}case 48:{tabella="u_lungo";break;}case 49:{tabella="u_marcia10km";break;}case 50:{tabella="u_martello";break;}case 51:{tabella="u_peso";break;}case 52:{tabella="u_svedese";break;}case 53:{tabella="u_triplo";break;}
            default:{break;}
        }

        mDbHelper=new DbHelper(ctx2, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION, res);

    }

    public void open() {  //apriamo il database, rendendolo scrivibile e leggibile

        mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public void close() { //chiudiamo il database

        mDb.close();

    }

// Vediamo ora come aggiungere tabelle e campi alle tabelle del db

/*  public void insertPerson(String name,String punt) { //metodo per inserire i dati

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PersonMetaData.PERSON_NAME_KEY, name);
        cv.put(PersonMetaData.PERSON_AGE_KEY, punt);
        mDb.insert(PersonMetaData.PERSON_TABLE, null, cv);

    }*/

/*  public Cursor fetchProducts() { //metodo per fare la query di tutti i dati

        return mDb.query(PersonMetaData.PERSON_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,null);

    }*/

    public Cursor searchLabel(String s) {
        return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT _id, prestazione, punteggio FROM " + tabella + " WHERE prestazione || ' ' || punteggio LIKE ?", 
                new String[]{"%" + s + "%"});
    }

static class PersonMetaData {  // i metadati della tabella, accessibili ovunque

/*  static final String PERSON_TABLE = tabella;
*/  static final String ID = "_id";
    static final String PERSON_NAME_KEY = "prestazione";
    static final String PERSON_AGE_KEY = "punteggio";

}

/*public static final String PERSON_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  //codice sql di creazione della tabella

+ tabella + " ("
+ PersonMetaData.ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ PersonMetaData.PERSON_NAME_KEY + " text not null, "
+ PersonMetaData.PERSON_AGE_KEY + " text not null"
+ "');";
*/




}
```

**DbHelper.java**

```
package it.gorlux.onyourmark;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { //classe che ci aiuta nella creazione del db

    int item;
    Context ctx;

    public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version, int item) {

        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.item = item;
        this.ctx = context;

    }

@Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) { //solo quando il db viene creato, creiamo la tabella

    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource( item );
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;

    try {
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            _db.execSQL(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

/*      _db.execSQL(MyDatabase.PERSON_TABLE_CREATE);

        String[] queries = MyDatabase.exec.split(";");
        for(String query : queries){
            _db.execSQL(query);
        }

        String[] queries2 = MyDatabase.exec2.split(";");
        for(String query : queries2){
            _db.execSQL(query);
        }*/

    }

public void execute(SQLiteDatabase _db, String s) {
    _db.execSQL(s);
}

@Override

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //qui mettiamo eventuali modifiche al db, se nella nostra nuova versione della app, il db cambia numero di versione

    }

}
```

**u_4x100 (working file)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS u_4x100 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, prestazione text, punteggio text);
INSERT INTO u_4x100 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (1, '37.40', '1300');
INSERT INTO u_4x100 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (2, '38.10', '1207');
INSERT INTO u_4x100 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (3, '38.80', '1129');
INSERT INTO u_4x100 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (4, '39.59', '1059');
.....
```

**u_4x200 (one of the not working files)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS u_4x200 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, prestazione text, punteggio text);
INSERT INTO u_4x200 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (1, '1:18.68', '1300');
INSERT INTO u_4x200 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (2, '1:19.53', '1230');
INSERT INTO u_4x200 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (3, '1:20.51', '1160');
INSERT INTO u_4x200 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (4, '1:21.72', '1090');
INSERT INTO u_4x200 (_id, prestazione, punteggio) VALUES (5, '1:23.41', '1020');
.....
```

Thanks for your support:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this may help you :

i think you should put this **_db.execSQL(line) and _db.execSQL(s)**   code inside try catch block ;

inside DbHelper.java

Change

```
      while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        _db.execSQL(line);
    }
```

to

```
   while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        try 
        {
        _db.execSQL(line);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
```

and

```
       _db.execSQL(s);
```

to

```
       try{  _db.execSQL(s);}
       catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I discovered that it was a problem of not refresh of the database! So the problem was that I didn't write the onUpgrade method in MyDatabase.java, and at first click on an item of the list view all worked well, but going back on the screen and clicking another item, the app tried to create another database with same name, so crashed! Now I temporarily use the solution that I create a new database every time someone click, then I'll write the onupgrade method properly! Thanks :)

Comment: ok :) good ! but app should not crash if it tries to create database with same name, i.e it should handle the exception instead of crashing !

Comment: Sorry i said it in a bad way, it does throw the exception :)